# How do I exclude search results in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am attempting to write an ActiveRecord Query which will return the records of all characters and non_player_characters in the same square as the current_user, while excluding the current_user from the result.

```
class Square
  def self.characters(user)
    characters = []
    players = Character.all
    bots = NonPlayerCharacter.all
    characters << bots.find_by(x_coordinate: user.x_coordinate, y_coordinate: user.y_coordinate)
    characters << players.find_by(x_coordinate: user.x_coordinate, y_coordinate: user.y_coordinate)
  end
end
```

I read [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions), it told me how to exclude items from my search results but only in the context of a single command. In other words, after reading it I could not figure out how to chain not conditions with the find_by method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_by` doesnt return an active record relation, use `where` that you can continue to modify:

```
players = Character.where(your conditions)
players = players.where.not(id: user.id)
# ...
```

Alternatively you can build a relation, and then call `find_by` on that relation.

```
players = Character.where.not(id: user.id)
players = players.where(some other conditions)
# ...
players.find_by(your conditions)
```

Comment: `find_by` doesnt return a relation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that find_by only returns 1 record, while where returns all records. Getting both sets of records (While excluding user) and concatenating them gave me the flatten array I needed. Thanks!